# Automatic tag creation for own sectioning commands in TeXShop

Tags: texshop

The title says it all: TeXShop automatically creates tags in the tex source for "standard" sectioning commands (`\chapter`, `\section`, etc.). Of course, tags can also be created manually via `%: tag name`, but is there a way to ammend the internal list of sectioning commands?

I.e., say I have a sectioning command `\mysection`, is there a way to make TeXShop automatically add a tag in the source at every call of `\mysection`?