# Prevent TeXShop from creating xml tags for frames

Tags: beamer, texshop, xml

TeXshop has the somewhat handy feature of automatically creating XML tags for each subsection, which greatly simplifies navigation in large latex documents. However, I am currently writing lecture notes using beamer, and it generates a xml tag for each single frame, creating clutter. Is there a way to avoid generating this many xml tags?

(I want to keep only those from sections, subsections, paragraphs, and my own custom tags, if possible).

This is what the xml tags "jump to" menu looks like on my TeXShop:
[image: xml tags drop down menu on TeXshop]
and these are the options given in the preferences panel:
[image: xml tags preferences in TeXshop]

The use of tags is described on page 8 of the [user manual](https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/TeXShopManual-2006.pdf). Following the instructions there, I managed to turn off all but personal tags by typing `defaults write TeXShop TagSections NO` into the Apple terminal. (Attempting to do the same thing by unchecking the boxes in the preference window didn't seem to have any effect.) That's useful, but I'm still looking for how to turn them back on for just sections and the like, for example as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276946/automatic-tag-creation-for-own-sectioning-commands-in-texshop).

Comment: XML tags? Can you please show an example of this?

Comment: @daleif Sure, I added a screenshot of what it looks like on my mac.

Comment: And what exactly does it use this for? Do they end up in the latex file or are they only used by TeXShop somehow?

Comment: @daleif I have no idea how they come into existence. :) I just find them pretty useful to navigate the code file once they are there. They allow TeXshop to jump to the section in the code file, or to any line that you start with `%: some_personal_mark`. I will look into the coding behind it though...

Comment: TeXShop has some features for folks using PreTeXt which uses XML files that can be converted to TeX files, etc. The `XML Tag Choices` are specifically for PreTeXt .xml files and not, as you are using them, for the Tags used with TeX files. Please write to the author of TeXShop to discuss the ability to turn off the frame tag.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Thanks for that clarification. That's probably why unchecking them didn't change anything on the dropdown menu. :)